# Portable indoor VHF antenna for SDR

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, vhf, portable

I want to make / buy VHF antenna that can meet the requirements below:

1. Portable (easy to install and transport).
2. Indoor (I want to install the antenna at a windowsill).
3. Low noise level, no (or not many) noise peaks at the spectrum.
4. Only for RX.

I have tried dipole and 2-element yagi, but it seems that they do not work properly without outdoor placement. The main issue that the noise level is great and the signal levels are low. I tried to place the antennas at a balcony and they received signals much better. Also, when I touched dipole section, the noise level became lower, I do not know why that happened.

So, the questions are:

1. What antenna design can meet my requirements?
2. What parameters do influence the noise level?

Comment: What frequency range do you need the antenna for? Desired range and absolute minimum? Do you have a hard limit on the size of the antenna, packaged or deployed?

Comment: VFH range (136 - 174 MHz), the size is limited to a size of rucksack

Answer (score 1):

One parameter affecting received noise levels is proximity to the noise source(s).

You can reduce this received noise by finding the noise sources in your indoor area, and unplugging all of them or turning them off.  Or by moving the Rx antenna farther away from the noise sources.  Or, if the noise sources are localized to a single spot, by using a directional loop antenna.